# WIN2003/IIS6 Ping to Site with Unique IP Times Out

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am adding a new site on a server running other sites, some 'All Unassigned' (those that do not need an SSL) and the is the 4th site with a unique IP (these require an SSL). All other sites, including their SSLs (if applicable) are working.

When I ping the LAN IP from within the network, I get 'request timed out'. Pings to the other unique IPs get a response.

I've tried:

- other unique LAN IPs
- created a new website in IIS6
- created a 'test' folder and pointed IIS there
- Event Viewer logs for System or Application show no error messages.

I restarted IIS after each variation.

- To my knowledge, pinging from within the network does not go thru my firewall, so I have not fooled with it.
- an ASP.NET version issue would ping but throw a browser error, so I have not fooled with it.

Any thoughts on how to debug this issue?

Any suggestions welcome, and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the IP address to the network configuration on the Windows machine? 
Ping doesn't have anything to do with your web server configuration or IIS.

To debug:
Make sure under Control Panel -> Network - > under TCP/IP Configuration that your server has the required IPs entered and that your subnet mask entries are correct.

Ping from the command line, so start - > run -> cmd
then at the prompt ping -ip address-

Make sure that your windows firewall is allowing ICMP packets in and out. If your network is protected from the internet by a separate firewall, you can turn the Windows firewall off to test.

Comment: Sweet. Solved by adding IP to Panel > Network > TCP/IP > Advanced. But I don't remember doing this on the other sites requiring a unique IP, although they were listed. Probably impaired from weekend! Thx